# Wrong Result of IIF function in MDX

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, iif-function

I have written a query as mentioned below:

```
WITH 
  SET [kpi_study] AS 
    {[study].[study].[BHC June12]} 
  SET [geographic] AS 
    {[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[HP]} 
  SET [brand] AS 
    {[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]} 
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF
    (
      'All' = 'All'
     ,[education].[education].MEMBERS
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[tom]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  {[kpi_study]*[geographic]*[brand]};
```

Result:Tom:4.19

Instead of **All** if i am passing(**SSC/HSC**) any other value always getting same value.Can any help me where i am doing wrong.it means IIF function is not working proper.

Comment: `Instead of All if i am passing(SSC/HSC) any other value always getting same value` - can you explain what you mean with the help of an example and edit the original question?

Comment: @sourava: Here All is a parameter value coming through based on the selection.if i am getting all then it would include all the member and provide me combine result otherwise it would give me that particular result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following:

```
 SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF
    (
      'All' = 'All'
     ,[education].[education].MEMBERS
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    )
```

So I'm guessing `All` are placeholders ?! - and you say when you change one of them nothing happens.

This is because in your select you're not actually using the `SET` called `[edu12]` so why would anything change?

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[tom]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  {[kpi_study]*[geographic]*[brand]};
```

Is `[edu12]` supposed to be on rows?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Here All is a value coming through parameter based on the selection.I just want to return only measure value.based on my condition thats why i don't define [edu12] as rows

Comment: solve the problem by using below mentioned query.
    
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF
    (
      'All' = 'All'
     ,[education].[education].MEMBERS
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[t] AS
      (SUM([edu12],[Measures].[tom]))
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[t]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]